# Default associations configuration keeps getting reapplied

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, file-association

I've configured a GPO that configures the default associations (For IE and Adobe Reader).
I'm talking about [this GPO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/set-the-default-browser-using-group-policy).
In my GPO, I redirect our users to an AppAssoc.xml that is located on our sysvol share so it is accessible for everyone.

The GPO is working just fine and all default associations are made. But I want users to be able to make changes to these default associations. Now when they make changes, the changes are reverted back on next logon.

Even in the above article it is explained that should still be able to change these settings.
[Here is an other information page](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsExplorer::DefaultAssociationsConfiguration) about the GPO that says that users are still able to override default file type and protocol associations.

Comment: How exactly are the users changing the file association.  This information is necessary to write the best possible answer to your question.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  What your trying to accomplish is confusing, if you want users to change the default file association, the you shouldn’t be managing it with a group policy at all.

Comment: They change the file association with right click on the file > open with > set as default.
We only want the default application for PDF and web pages configured. But we want to give our users the option to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the GPO I mentioned since it kepts reapplying. Which was unwanted behavior.

Since old computers that already had this GPO applied are good, I've configured an extra step in the task sequence in MDT for new computers.

```
dism.exe /online /import-defaultappassociations:%SCRIPTROOT%\AppAssoc\AppAssoc.xml
```

This way the default behavior is what we want AND the users have the option to change it without these changes being reverted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, GPO will be applied at every logon time.

If you want to apply the file association group policy only on first log on,  as workaround, you may consider of using Script to configure file association registry entry. And applied the script only at user first logon.

Steps mentioned in “How To Run a Logon Script One Time When a New User Logs On in Windows Server 2003” can be considered as a reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325347/how-to-run-a-logon-script-one-time-when-a-new-user-logs-on-in-windows

Best Regards,
Eve Wang